# Call ImageJ macro from LabVIEW

Tags: labview, imagej, fiji

I have developed a imagej(fiji) macro program(.ijm) to stitch images.
I want to call this macro from LabVIEW. I am using LabVIEW as frontend and imagej as backend.

I tried a labview program to call ijm macro but was not sucessful.

Expected : I should get stitched image

Comment: Please give more detail of what you tried and what you want to achieve. Does your macro work in [headless mode](https://imagej.net/Headless)? If so have you tried running it from a command line using LabVIEW's System Exec function?

Comment: I have used Imagej(Fiji) software to stitch images using plugin Grid/collection stitching. I have recorded a macro program based on grid/collection stitching. I want my Macro program to run through labview where user can provide details of stitching like number of rows, columns, overlap, etc. Can you share your email. I will send the work I have done till.

Answer (score 0):

ImageJ can be run from the command line in "headless" mode as discussed in [this forum thread](https://forum.image.sc/t/running-plugins-macros-from-the-command-line/363/3):

```
ImageJ-win64.exe --headless --console -macro RunBatch.ijm
```

Note that you will probably have to give it the complete paths to the executable and to the macro. And since these paths may contain spaces, you should surround them with double quotes.

[Sample LabView code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhWQT.png)